# Tensorflow : convolutional autoencoder via subclassing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was playing with some Keras samples, defining models through subclassing, but I can't get it working.

```
from keras import layers, Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os

class Encoder(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, name: str = "encoder"):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._conv16 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name="conv16")
        self._conv8 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name="conv8")
        self._max_pool = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name="max_pool")
        
    def call(self, inputs: np.ndarray):
        x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
#         x = self._conv16(inputs)
#         x = self._max_pool(x)
#         x = self._conv8(x)
#         x = self._max_pool(x)
#         x = self._conv8(x)
#         encoded = self._max_pool(x)
        return encoded

class Decoder(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, name: str = "decoder"):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._conv16 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name="conv16")
        self._conv8 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name="conv8")
        self._conv1 = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name="conv1")
        self._up_sampling = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2), name="up_samp")
        
        
    def call(self, inputs: np.ndarray):
        x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
        x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
        x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
        decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
#         x = self._conv8(inputs)
#         x = self._up_sampling(x)
#         x = self._conv8(x)
#         x = self._up_sampling(x)
#         x = self._conv16(x)
#         x = self._up_sampling(x)
#         decoded = self._conv1(x)
        return decoded

class Autoencoder(Model):

    def __init__(self, name: str = "autoencoder"):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = Decoder()

    def call(self, inputs: np.ndarray):
        encoded = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructed = self.decoder(encoded)
        return reconstructed       

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

autoencoder = Autoencoder()
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test)
```

First of all, I can't get the commented code working. Whenever I try to use it, I get errors such "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv8" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1of input shape to have value 1, but received input with shape (60000, 56, 56, 8)". I can't spot a difference in the model definition.

Secondly, running the above code gives me:

> ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, there are many issues that need to be addressed. For example,

- **Issue 1**: In the `call` method, the `inputs` argument should be tensor and not numpy array.
- **Issue 2**: In model subclassing, you should initiate the **trainable layer** in the `init` method or `build` method and use the instances in the `call` function. It's the reason for the following error that you got.

> ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables were created on the first call. Make sure the tf. Variable is only created once or created outside tf. function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.

- **Issue 3**: In your encoder block, it seems that you used `self._conv8` twice, which happens also in the decoder block. It shouldn't be like that. If you need to call them twice (or multiple times), you need to initiate each of them in the `init` (or `build`) method independently. I think it's one of the so-called downsides of subclassing approach that you need to initiate the N times layer in `init` and forward their instances in the `call` method another N times. It's the reason for the following error that you got. ( Side note, passing the same input to the same trainable layer is also referred to as weight sharing, which I don't think it's the intention here. )

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv8" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1of input shape to have value 1, but received input with shape (60000, 56, 56, 8)

---

## Solution

By addressing the above issue, here is the working code. Also, note that it's better and proper to import `keras` from `tensorflow`.

**Encoder**

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import numpy as np

class Encoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, name: str = "encoder"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self._conv16   = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', 
                                       padding='same', name="conv16")
        self._conv8    = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', 
                                       padding='same', name="conv8")
        self._max_pool = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same',
                                              name="max_pool")
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self._conv16(inputs)
        x = self._max_pool(x)
        encoded = self._conv8(x)
        return encoded
```

**Decoder**

```
class Decoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, name: str = "decoder"):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._conv16 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 
                               activation='relu', 
                               padding='same', name="conv16")
        self._conv8  = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), 
                               activation='relu', 
                               padding='same', name="conv8")
        self._conv1  = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), 
                               activation='sigmoid', 
                               padding='same', name="conv1")
        self._up_sampling = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2), name="up_samp")
        
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self._conv8(inputs)
        x = self._up_sampling(x)
        x = self._conv16(x)
        decoded = self._conv1(x)
        return decoded
```

**Autoencoder**

```
class Autoencoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, name: str = "autoencoder"):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = Decoder()

    def call(self, inputs):
        encoded = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructed = self.decoder(encoded)
        return reconstructed
```

**Execute**

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

autoencoder = Autoencoder()
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

Epoch 1/5
12ms/step - loss: 0.1100 - val_loss: 0.0676
Epoch 2/5
12ms/step - loss: 0.0666 - val_loss: 0.0651
Epoch 3/5
12ms/step - loss: 0.0649 - val_loss: 0.0641
Epoch 4/5
12ms/step - loss: 0.0642 - val_loss: 0.0635
Epoch 5/5
11ms/step - loss: 0.0636 - val_loss: 0.0631
```

**Predict**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

y_pred = autoencoder.predict(x_test)

ax[0].imshow(x_test[10, :,:, 0])
ax[1].imshow(y_pred[10, :,:, 0])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your patience and detailed information. I got a bit lost in the docs trying to understand how to properly use that subclassing strategy.